# out of memory error in J2ME..?

Tags: java, java-me

I am getting this out of memory error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: <classname>: Unable to expand permanent memory
```

I am getting this error while i am taking a reflect instant of a class in J2ME.

Comment: Why? When? What? Which code? Be spesific please..

Comment: When i added this statement  `Class c  = Class.forName("someclass"); Object obj = c.newInstance();`  this **'someclass'** is not being created. i get out of memory error. Here someclass is   renders Items into mobile as form

Comment: Please put on your code here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try allocating more space to the jvm.  This is an [example](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-135801.html) of how to do it.

One possible cause for this could be that you have a memory leak which is far too common.  There are a lot of tools that you can use to help diagnose and fix these issues.  [WTK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-135801.html) is one of them, but there are others.

Comment: sorry I will edit my post, there is a tool that seems pretty good for javaME